# Starting current of DC motor Simscape model does not match the datasheet of the motor

Tags: current, dc-motor, matlab, simulink

I have the datasheet of a brushed DC motor and I am trying to model it in MATLAB using Simscape blocks.

I entered all the required parameters in the DC motor block but when I run the simulation the peak value of the starting current (inrush current) does not match the datasheet.

Can someone help me to figure out the issue in my model?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Where, on that data sheet, is the in-rush current stated?

Comment: Hello Mike, I am sorry earlier i haven't posted the datasheet of the motor. I just edited my post and attached the motor datasheet. It says the starting current (inrush current) is 40 A.